# java.security.AccessControlException: Multithreading in App engine with Basic Scaling

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using GAE for my backend(module created through Android Studio). I added a library that helps in sending FCM messages to FCM Cloud Connection Server but this library spawns threads to handle things which is where I am getting this exception for trying to spawn threads.

Now, I know that TaskQueue API is provided for this purpose but the library is not under my control.

How can I get around problems with using 3rd party libs that use concurrency?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, **You can't**, and definitely not in the Google App Engine Standard.

I had to complement my standard GAE App with a Flexible microservice specifically for sending messages.

For anyone searching, here is the ref: [GAE Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/)